# Android two listview vertically using 50%-50% of the screen height

Tags: android, listview

I would like to use two `ListViews` in one screen vertically one below the other and also the two `ListView` equally take 50%-50% of the screen. My problem is, I created the layout, in `eclipse` (graphical layout) looks great but in the device it wont take the half of the screen. It seems depends of the content of the `ListView`. How can I do it right ??

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:background="#f0f0f0"
    android:weightSum="1.0">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dip"
        android:textSize="18sp"
        android:textStyle="bold"
        android:gravity="left"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Some Text" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#FB0"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip" />

        <ListView
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="10dip"
            android:layout_weight="0.5"
            android:background="#FB0"
            android:scrollbars="none"
            android:dividerHeight="2dip" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Have you tried to replace `android:layout_height="fill_parent"` with `android:layout_height="0dp"` in both?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should introduce `LinearLayout` and use `layout_weight`, while setting `layout_height="0dp"`.

Here is an example:

```
<TextView 
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent">

        <ListView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.5" />

        <ListView
           android:layout_width="fill_parent"
           android:layout_height="0dp"
           android:layout_weight="0.5" />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Thanks, i missed this case :) I tried with separate linear layouts and i set the weight for them, now it seems to work.

Comment: Its not working. I had a best case then when both layout had mostly same size, but if the first listview contains much more elements then the height was incrased. Interesting the graphical layout designer shows both are using only the half space.

Comment: Can you please update you question with your current layout and also add a screenshot of what you see?

Comment: Thx inzaruk, i resolved in other way. (The height was calculated programmatically)