# how to split list view in an activity

Tags: android

I have a requirement that I need to display as many elements as possible in listview.

I have some 50 elements in my listview , so to display many elemnts I decided to split the listview in two parts , means half of my activity screen will display some elements and second half will display some more elements....

Please help if its possible to draw the listview in two parts, if not please let me know if ther's any aletrnative.. The data in a listview is dynamic..

I am using Android version3.2..

Comment: This post here also has some information: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094380/android-two-listview-vertically-using-50-50-of-the-screen-height

Answer (score 0):

So it sounds like you need to implement multiple listviews within a single activity. This [stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/q/3405211/527288) is probably what you're looking for.