# Set ListView Item to half ScreenWidth in XML

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-listview, listitem

In XML, I have a custom list item view that I am inflating within the getView() method of my adapter for my ListView. In XML, how can I make my custom ListView item always half the width of the screen (maybe add some padding too)? I don't think adding another widget would work like the suggested solutions I've seen since this is a list item.

Edit:

To clarify, I don't think this is a problem with my xml code, but here's what I mean. If I have a custom layout like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:weightSum="1.0"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" 
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="218dp"
        android:layout_height="212dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

I have a hardcoded width (which I don't think is best practice) so I want to make that width 1/2 of the screen total width. Clearly, this XML is much simplified but I hope it gets across the question.

Apologies if I am missing something rather obvious.

**Edit**:

Adding another Layout that has the same solves this.

**Edit 2**:
Never mind. I've noticed the following behavior:
If I add another layout, it'll inflate *everything* and so I'll literally get half empty space width for each list item. I have to make the top most layout half the screen width I guess. How can I approach this?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6094380/android-two-listview-vertically-using-50-50-of-the-screen-height

Comment: can add xml code of custome layout of listview

Comment: @hakiko I am able to have a 50/50 width relation between the two ListViews in the Activity, but the custom layout I am inflating _to put in each list item_ is cut off in both ListViews because its width is more than 50% of the screen. That is my issue.

Comment: please show us some code

Comment: I have added some code @Nezam

Answer (score 2):

main.xml

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context=".MainActivity" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <ListView
            android:id="@+id/listView1"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content" >
        </ListView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:orientation="vertical" >
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

itemlist.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/root"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#000000"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:orientation="horizontal" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Large Text"
        android:textAppearance="?android:attr/textAppearanceLarge" />
</LinearLayout>
```

MainActivity.java

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

 static final String TAG_NAME = "name";
 static final String TAG_ID = "id";
 static String selected = "";

ListView listView;


HashMap<String, String> map;
ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> myList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    myList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();       
    listView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    fillListView();
}

private void fillListView() {

    myList.clear();

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TAG_ID,"1");
    map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name1");
    myList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TAG_ID,"2");
    map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name2");
    myList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TAG_ID,"3");
    map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name3");
    myList.add(map);

    map = new HashMap<String, String>();
    map.put(TAG_ID,"4");
    map.put(TAG_NAME, "Name4");
    myList.add(map);

    listView.setAdapter(new MyListAdapter(this, R.layout.itemlist, myList));

}
private class MyListAdapter extends BaseAdapter 
{

    private List<HashMap<String,String>> List;
    private LayoutInflater mInflater;
    private int layoutresource;

    public MyListAdapter(Context context,int resource,List<HashMap<String, String>> myList) {
        List = myList;
        mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(context);
        layoutresource = resource;
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return List.size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getItem(int position) {
        return List.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public long getItemId(int position) {
        return position;
    }

    @Override
    public View getView(final int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        if (convertView == null) {
            convertView = mInflater.inflate(layoutresource,null);
        }    

         final View rootView = convertView.findViewById(R.id.root);

        ImageView imageView = (ImageView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.imageView1);
        final TextView name = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);

        imageView.setImageDrawable(getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.profile));
        name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));
        name.setText(List.get(position).get(TAG_NAME));

        if ( List.get(position).get(TAG_ID).equals(selected))
            name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ff0000"));
        else
            name.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#ffffff"));


        rootView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                selected = List.get(position).get(TAG_ID);
                fillListView();
            }
        });

        name.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rootView.performClick();
            }
        });

        imageView.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                rootView.performClick();
            }
        });

        return convertView;
    }
}
```

}

Comment: My problem is not in the main activity. It is setting the width of the custom layout _list item_.

Comment: Yes, I just figured this out as well. I'll give you credit for the answer, then. Thanks.

Comment: I think,there is no need to add an extra view.

Comment: i use the extra view that use the 50% width of the screen

Comment: can you see my edit? That extra view is also inflated, so my item becomes half empty space (obviously an unfavorable result)

Comment: Please change the xml that contain listview and make the listview that use exactly the 50% width of screen using weight

Answer (score 1):

simplify

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
          android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
          android:layout_width="match_parent"
          android:layout_height="match_parent"
          android:orientation="horizontal"
          android:paddingTop="10dp">
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:layout_height="212dp"
        android:layout_gravity="right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher" />
<View android:layout_height="0dp"
      android:layout_width="0dp"
      android:layout_weight="1"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

there is only one view(imageview) inside your listitem.so you should half the width of listview instead of list item.but if you really want to half the width of listitem then give the following code a try,I hope it will be helpful.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/LinearLayout1"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:weightSum="10"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:paddingTop="10dp" 
    >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/item_image"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_weight="5"
        android:layout_height="212dp"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"

        android:scaleType="fitCenter"
        android:src="@drawable/..." />

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: I'd like to do it this way. When I do this, I can't get it to move to the center. Any suggestion?

Comment: yes,just set the gravity of parent view.check my updated answer.